# how to give the constraints to series of 5 UILabels in the custom uitableview using storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, constraints

AS I am new to the iOS application.In my storyboard i am having the serious of 5 uilables in custom cell uitableview .can anyone suggest me how to give the constraints for all this 5 labels . Also added the screen shot for your         reference.

[image]

Comment: You can set multiplier for your width constraint.

Comment: use UIstackview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **stackView** for this

**1.Embed 5 label in StackView**

[image]

**2.make StackView equal proportionally**

**3.Add space as much as you want in spacing property (ex: i added 20 space to each label)**

[image]

**My Output (for clarity, i have given yellow bg color to label )**

[image]